# How to return Promise<string> after user clicks "OK" button in a modal window?

Tags: typescript, promise, angular5

I want to show a modal window asking for input e.g: "Your new password:" by calling a function returning Promise after user clicks the "OK" button.

Code that would be called after clicking a button to change password:

```
ChangePassword()
{
 modal.PasswordModal().then(res => {/*set new password*/})
                      .catch(msg => {/*resolve error*/})
}
```

Code that would return Promise and show the modal window with input.

```
PasswordModal() : Promise<string>
{
 this.PasswordModalVisible = true
 //How to wait for the user to press the "OK" button?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very easy solution for this if you are using or can use `rxjs`.

Basically,

1. you create a promise where you subscribe to a locally defined observable.
2. When user clicks OK (or cancel), you can publish a boolean to the observable.
3. This subscription function will receive the boolean, and can then resolve or reject the promise based on the boolean value.

Here's the sample code:

```
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';

export class ModalClass {

    okOperation$ = new Subject();
    newPassword: string;

    passwordModal() : Promise<string>
    {
        this.PasswordModalVisible = true;

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            // Wait for the user to press the "OK" or "CANCEL" button?
            this.okOperation$.subscribe((success: boolean) => {
                if (success) {
                    resolve(this.newPassword);
                } else {
                    reject('User clicked cancel');
                }
            });

        });
    }

    okClicked() {
        this.okOperation$.next(true);
    }

    cancelClicked() {
        this.okOperation$.next(false);
    }
}

export class DemoClass {        

    constructor(private modal: ModalClass) {}

    changePassword()
    {
        this.modal
            .passwordModal()
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res); // New Password                   
                /*set new password*/
            })
            .catch(msg => {
                console.log(msg); // User clicked cancel                    
                /*resolve error*/
            });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The desired effect can be achieved in a following sequence:

1. The function-creator creates a promise object that doesn't have an associated execution block, thus allowing for promise chain to be created without explicitly starting any execution process.
2. All the necessary setup happens, a reference is left retained to this promise object, as well as returning this promise object in the function-creator.
3. Event handlers should capture the promise object and `fulfill` and `reject` as appropriate.